# Parse JSON to map with array

Tags: java, json, jackson

Here is a sample json:

```
{"LIST_OF_IDS_FOR_RETRANSFER":["50, 39, 29"]}
```

Now I'm trying to parse this json to map with no luck:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> params = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Map<String, List<Integer>>>(){});
```

The result is the Map with one entry:

key: LIST_OF_IDS_FOR_RETRANSFER

value: List with size=1, value is '50, 39, 29'.

But I want to get List with size=3. Is it possible to achieve with Jackson?

Comment: Well you are quite literally trying to parse an array consisting of a single string "50, 39, 29". Did you mean: `{"LIST_OF_IDS_FOR_RETRANSFER":[50, 39, 29]}`? If not, you can simply split the `LIST_OF_IDS_FOR_RETRANSFER` on `, ` to extract the ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your type reference is `Map<String, List<Integer>>`, then your JSON should look like this: `{"LIST_OF_IDS_FOR_RETRANSFER":[50, 39, 29]}` (remove the "" around the numbers).